# what is the purpose of table variables in SQL

Tags: sql

Hi its my first question just trying to break the ice. 
Something that I have yet understood is the meaning of commands like this one:

```
SELECT name, continent, population FROM world x 
  WHERE 25000000> ALL
    (SELECT population FROM world y 
        WHERE y.continent=x.continent
          AND area>0)
```

I do not really know why the table variables were used here. Could somebody let me know and possibly translate this in to common English for me?

Comment: The question was edited for you already, but one helpful tip in future would be to format your code: [read this to see how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow!

What you are looking at are actually called [table aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).  Basically, they tell the rest of the query that if you mention something called `x`, you are actually referring to the table known as `world`.  This is handy if, as in your scenario, you are trying to reference the same table twice: if you want to match `world.continent` to `world.continent`, it needs to know which is which.

Another common usage is simply to save space: if you refer to a table named `My_Extremely_Long_Table_With_An_Awful_Name`, you don't want to write that out every time.  You can alias it to be `foo`, `yak`, `blueberry`, `x`, `a`, `meltwaan`, or anything else you have a chance of remembering, and then refer to it that way for the rest of the time.

Finally, aliases are occasionally absolutely required - [such as when you join to a subquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

You can read more about it at the links I embedded in the answer, or through a search for 'Table Alias'.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the x and y tokens, then those are called [table aliases](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp).  It allows you to create a short 'alias' temporary name for a table type so you don't have to write the entire table name out for the join/where clause.

Answer (score 0):

As others have already mentioned, these are called table *aliases*.

> Aliases provide database administrators, as well as other database users, with the ability to reduce the amount of code required for a query, and to make queries generally simpler to understand. In addition, aliasing can be used as an obfuscation technique to protect the real names of database fields.

Read more on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alias_(SQL)).

Generally they're used to reduce the amount of code when your table and/or column names are really long (e.g. `organization_student_exam_files` can be aliased to `xf` or something similarly shorter.

Another, more important, use of table aliases would be to disambiguate the same column names in two tables in the same query. For instance:

```
SELECT id, name FROM dogs LEFT JOIN owners ON oid = id;
```

This query won't work if both `dogs` and `owners` have a column called `id` because the system won't know which `id` to use. Same with selecting the `name`, name of dog or name of owner? Therefore:

```
SELECT d.id, d.name, o.name FROM dogs AS d LEFT JOIN owners AS o ON oid = id;
```

This allows me to select both the dog's name and owner's name in the same query.